# Entity Framework Core Navigational property naming convention after scafold

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am generating dbcontext from existing database and generating navigation properties have strange names. I would like to rename them.

This is my scafold command:

`Scaffold-DbContext "data source=-;initial catalog=dbtest;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DbContext -UseDatabaseNames`

Generated class:

```
public DateTimeOffset? update_date { get; set; }
public Guid? update_admin_id { get; set; }
public virtual Admin admin_ { get; set; }
public virtual Role role_nameNavigation { get; set; }
```

Desired class:

```
public DateTimeOffset? update_date { get; set; }
public Guid? update_admin_id { get; set; }
public virtual Admin Admin { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
```

Thanks for you help in advance.